# SQL Is NULL breaking my results

Tags: sql

I've got the following query. It works most time, but fails on occasions and I can't pin point why. I've narrowed down the line that is causing it to fail as it's only happened to me once in a week, but my colleagues have reported it a number of times, is there a better way to write it?

The line I believe that is making the SQL fail is `(LessonSubject.StartDate<=? OR LessonSubject.StartDate IS NULL)`, but specifically the `LessonSubject.StartDate IS NULL` command as `LessonSubject.StartDate<=?` returns some data. While dissecting my query, I did remove `(LessonSubject.EndDate>=? OR LessonSubject.EndDate IS NULL)` but I suppose once I add this line it will have the same behaviour and break my code.

What I am trying to do is retrieve data if `lessonSubject.StartDate` is empty or my parameter `?` is less than `lessonsubject.startdate`.

Any help would be much appreciated. Like I said it's working most of the time, but occasionally it fails and I can't pin point why, but I suspect it's the `startdate IS NULL` condition that's making it fail.

```
SELECT PeriodList.pk_PeriodListID, CASE PeriodList.DayShort 
    WHEN 'M' THEN '" & $mon & "' 
    WHEN 'Tu' THEN '" & $tues & "' 
    WHEN 'W' THEN '" & $wed & "' 
    WHEN 'Th' THEN '" & $thurs & "' 
    WHEN 'F' THEN '" & $fri & "' 
    WHEN 'S' THEN '" & $sat & "' 
    ELSE  '" & $sun & "' 
    END AS mydate, PeriodList.PeriodNumber, PeriodInformation.StartTime, PeriodInformation.EndTime, SubjectList.SubjectCode , RoomList.RoomCode, Staff.StaffID, Lesson.pk_LessonID, SetList.SetNumber, SetList.SetName, SetList.Form  

FROM PeriodList

LEFT JOIN PeriodInformation
ON PeriodList.pk_PeriodListID = PeriodInformation.fk_PeriodListID

LEFT JOIN Lesson
ON Lesson.fk_PeriodListID = PeriodInformation.fk_PeriodListID

LEFT JOIN LessonRoom
ON Lesson.pk_LessonID = LessonRoom.fk_LessonID

LEFT JOIN RoomList
ON LessonRoom.fk_RoomID = RoomList.pk_RoomID

LEFT JOIN LessonStaff
ON Lesson.pk_LessonID = LessonStaff.fk_LessonID

LEFT JOIN Staff
ON LessonStaff.fk_StaffID = Staff.pk_StaffID

LEFT JOIN LessonSubject
ON Lesson.fk_LessonSubjectID = LessonSubject.pk_LessonSubjectID

LEFT JOIN SubjectList
ON LessonSubject.fk_SubjectListID = SubjectList.pk_SubjectListID

LEFT JOIN SetList
ON SetList.pk_SetListID = LessonSubject.fk_SetListID

LEFT JOIN SetMember
ON SetMember.fk_SetListID = SetList.pk_SetListID

WHERE PeriodInformation.Rotation=? AND 
PeriodList.VersionCode=? AND  
(LessonSubject.StartDate<=? OR LessonSubject.StartDate IS NULL) AND 
(LessonSubject.EndDate>=? OR LessonSubject.EndDate IS NULL) AND
Setlist.fk_AcademicYearID=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Thumb Rule of `Outer Join's`(here `Left Outer Join`)

When you want to *filter*(`PeriodInformation.Rotation`,`Setlist.fk_AcademicYearID`) any records from the right table then you should move the filters to `ON` condition. When you put the right table filters in Where clause the `NULL` values(non matching records) will get rejected during comparison

```
FROM   periodlist 
       LEFT JOIN periodinformation 
              ON periodlist.pk_periodlistid = periodinformation.fk_periodlistid 
                 AND periodinformation.rotation = ? 
       LEFT JOIN lesson 
              ON lesson.fk_periodlistid = periodinformation.fk_periodlistid 
       LEFT JOIN lessonroom 
              ON lesson.pk_lessonid = lessonroom.fk_lessonid 
       LEFT JOIN roomlist 
              ON lessonroom.fk_roomid = roomlist.pk_roomid 
       LEFT JOIN lessonstaff 
              ON lesson.pk_lessonid = lessonstaff.fk_lessonid 
       LEFT JOIN staff 
              ON lessonstaff.fk_staffid = staff.pk_staffid 
       LEFT JOIN lessonsubject 
              ON lesson.fk_lessonsubjectid = lessonsubject.pk_lessonsubjectid 
                 AND lessonsubject.startdate <=? 
                 AND lessonsubject.enddate >=? LEFT 
       JOIN subjectlist 
         ON lessonsubject.fk_subjectlistid = subjectlist.pk_subjectlistid 
       LEFT JOIN setlist 
              ON setlist.pk_setlistid = lessonsubject.fk_setlistid 
                 AND setlist.fk_academicyearid = ? 
       LEFT JOIN setmember 
              ON setmember.fk_setlistid = setlist.pk_setlistid 
WHERE  periodlist.versioncode = ?
```

Comment: I doubt you cited the rule of thumb properly, because most of the time the correct place for a filter for the right-side table is the `where` clause, but in the OP's case the `where` clause specifically allows null values from `LessonSubject`.

Comment: @GSerg - but not for these two columns `PeriodInformation.Rotation,Setlist.fk_AcademicYearID`

Comment: No, but I seriously doubt this is what OP meant. Your code will give all records where `periodlist.versioncode = ?`, even when the left-joined columns do not satisfy their conditions (they will be `null`). *Sometimes* it's exactly what you want, but *most of the time* it isn't. Most of the time you want to filter on the left-joined columns too and remove the rows where the values do not match.

Comment: @GSerg - In that case OP's might use `INNER JOIN` not `LEFT JOIN`. May be I am wrong but I felt this is what OP is looking for

Comment: @Prdp Thanks for the code, trying to get it to work with my tables. Just double check, will your code find the lessonsubjects who don't have a startdate enddate? I don't think it will - but again IM new to this, hence the large filter in the where clause on my original query. I understand everything else you have done. Thanks